# CdkDrag moves way too fast

Tags: angular, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm facing some strange CdkDrag behavior, when draggable element is wider than container, even dragging for like few pixels, instantly drags to end of draggable element.

[image: CdkDrag Behavior]

Any idea how to make it drag smoothly, as it works with red square?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you has two functions that move the element (click) and (drag). You can has a variable "onDrag", so you can has some like

```
<div class="example-box" cdkDrag
  (cdkDragStarted)="onDrag=true"
  (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnded()"
  (click)="!onDrag && click()"
  >
  Drag me around
</div>
```

Im drag start we put the variable to true, in dragEnded we enclosed in a setTimeOut put the variable to false. the click check first the variable

```
  onDrag:boolean=false

  click()
  {
    console.log("click")
  }
  dragEnded()
  {
    setTimeout(()=>{
       this.onDrag=false
    })
  }
```

Comment: as I said in my post, the problem only appears when draggable element is wider than container. and it has nothing to do with any (click) event binding... btw, I don`t have any other event than (cdkDragMoved) and (cdkDragEnded)